# How to check if a String contains 3 digits or more

Tags: java, string

I'm currently trying to check if a string contains 3 digits or more. If it does, then it is valid. How can I fix it?

```
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");  //111Hello <-- valid
String word = input.nextLine();
boolean numbers = word.matches(".*\\d{3,}"); 
System.out.println(numbers);
```

Output:

`Invalid`

Here are some examples:

Input:
`Hello244`

Output: 
`Valid`

Input: 
`3Hello`

Output:
`Invalid`

Input: 
`6Hello2Hello5`

Output:
`Valid`

Comment: Do you know you can also search strings using `Matcher#find`? Currently you only match strings that *end with* three or more digits.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `match` - check the whole input string ; `find` - check part of the input string (finds the regular expression inside the string)  **but** posted code is sure not creating that output - please consider posting a [mcve]

Comment: This contains an error  `boolean numbers = word.match(".*\\d{3,}");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but pretty short and straightforward:

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\D","").length() > 2);
```

I prefer kaya3's solution the most

Answer (score 3):

This is easy to do using a regular expression, because the set of strings containing at least three digits is a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) - precisely what regular expressions are designed to recognise.

```java
public boolean hasThreeDigits(String s) {
    return s.matches(".*\\d.*\\d.*\\d.*");
}
```

The regex `.*\d.*\d.*\d.*` matches three digits with anything before, after or in between.

Comment: I've voted down because although it does answer the question, it doesn't show good use of regular expressions. As this seems a learning requirement I'd expect an answer that scales well.

Comment: Scaling to counting more digits is not stated as a requirement to the question. I disagree that it is good to write more complex code simply so that it's easier to adapt that code for a more complex problem.

Comment: The complexity of any code that uses regular expressions is in the regular expression. Just e.g. counting is much less of an issue. What would happen if, instead of a digit, you need e.g. to parse 3 x  a version string or similar?

Comment: I disagree. The complexity of the code in your answer comes from using a loop, a counter variable and two library classes Pattern and Matcher. Its complexity is not in the regular expression `\d` which you used.

If the regex being repeated were more complicated than `\d`, then of course you would write `.*(versionstring.*){3}` instead. But I don't think `.*(\d.*){3}` would be simpler or easier to understand than what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a counter and loop over each character and then test if its a digit?

This is pseudo code :

```
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");  //111Hello <-- valid
String word = input.nextLine();
int numberOfDigits = countDigits(word, 3);
if (numberOfDigits) >= 3{//...

int countDigits(String val, int max){
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < val.length(); i++){
        char c = val.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(c){
            cnt++;
        }
        if(cnt == max)return;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)

Comment: For this question, you can directly break the for-loop if `cnt` is equal to 3 to prevent redundant checking.

Comment: yes LHCHIN I thought its extra detail. I added it now.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this with regular expressions. That doesn't really seem required, but let's assume this is an assignment:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FindDigits {
    public static final Pattern DIGIT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\p{Digit}");

    private static int countDigits(String input) {
        final Matcher m = DIGIT_PATTERN.matcher(input);
        int c = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            c++;
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            final int c = countDigits(args[i]);
            System.out.printf("Input : \"%s\"%nOutput: %s%n", args[i], c >= 3 ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

This answer assumes that the input is a set of strings on the command line. It defines a function to count the occurrences of pattern consisting of a single digit. It could of course stop counting at 3.

I'm mainly posting this because `Matcher.find` is often overlooked as it doesn't have a convenience method defined in `String`. It often makes for much easier to read regular expressions as you don't need to define what you are **not** looking for. Otherwise you're stuck with regular expressions strings such as `".*\\d.*\\d.*\\d.*"` which are kind of horrible and do not scale well.

---

Instead of the while loop you can also use `m.results().count()` on a later version of the Java runtime. In that case a one-liner would be:

```
long count = Pattern.compile("\\p{Digit}").matcher(input).results().count();
```